# determining whether or not the following series is divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^{2}}]$$

I have a serious difficulty of grasping the way the general term apeears in this series.I am not looking for a solution, just a way to simplify this expression into something that is more abstract.

Comment: you can try to estimate the general term from above and below by the number of terms in the sum multiplied by correspondingly the minimum and maximum member in the brackets. This will greatly simplify the expression in brackets and will reveal a familiar picture.

Comment: Hints: Of the terms in your sum (inside the brackets), which is the smallest? How many terms are there total?

Comment: Such series is trivially divergent since its $n$-th term is greater than $\frac{1}{2n}$ and the harmonic series is divergent. To find $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\right]$$ is more interesting. It equals $\frac{\pi^2}{4}\log(2)-\zeta(3)$.